# Does the sequence of random variables $\{X_n\} \sim \mathcal{U}[0, 1/n]$ converges in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I believe it converges in probability to $0$.
Here is my work

$\forall \epsilon > 0$

$\mathbb{P}(|X_n - 0| \ge \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(X_n \ge \epsilon)$

Case I :- When $\epsilon \ge \frac{1}{n}$,

$\mathbb{P}(X_n \ge \epsilon) = 0$

Case II :- When $0 \lt \epsilon \lt \frac{1}{n}$,

$\mathbb{P}(X_n \ge \epsilon) = n*(\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon) = 1 - n\epsilon$.
Now how does this converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: For convergence in probability, you essentially fix $\epsilon$ here and consider $n\to \infty$. For any fixed $\epsilon > 0$, eventually $n$ will be such that $1/n \le \epsilon$. In other words, you only really need to worry about Case I (and understand why this is so).

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$ so

$\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists N$ such that $m>M$

$|\frac{1}{n}|=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$

(so always for every $\epsilon$, by take $n>N$ just case (1) happen). but to sure

so $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists N$ such that $n>N$

since $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ so $[\epsilon,\infty) \subset [\frac{1}{n},\infty) $ and $P$ is increasing so $P(X_n\geq \epsilon)\leq P(X_n\geq \frac{1}{n}) $

and its done